# Convenient approach to replace shared controller between two visualforce pages in LWC

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components

This is more of a conceptual question. I am currently replacing a salesforce classic functionality in which there are two visualforce pages involved, and only one controller sharing all the data.
Normally, the flow of the operation is VF1 ==> VF2 ==> VF1, and then a final operation is performed using data shared between the two visualforce pages.
So, what I decided, in LWC, is to navigate between two different lightning web components, sending by state (both lwc are wrapped in aura components for navigation) all the data needed in the second lwc, and then I thought of doing the same and send back the data I need again in my first lwc.

My question is, is it a better approach to insert the second lwc as a child component of the first one, and do a parent-child communication instead of navigation? I thought of this because when navigating back from the second lwc, the component is instantiated all over again, when in reality the logical thing is to keep all the data as it were before navigating.
So what I thought is to insert a conditional template in the html of the LWC1, like this:

```
<template if:false={showSecondLWC}>
     <!-- first component markup -->
</template>
<template if:true={showSecondLWC}>
     <c-second-lwc onreturn={getData}></c-second-lwc>
</template>
```

Is it a better approach like this? I'm curious and I think it would help me for the future, as I have more functionalities to convert to LWC...

Comment: I've done similar things in order to maintain a single-page flow and it seems to work well.  However, you mention Aura components - are you intending to have Aura components as children of an LWC?  If so, you cannot do that - an LWC can only have LWC children, but an Aura component can have LWC children (or a mix of LWC and Aura children).  My approach is generally one big Aura parent that maintains the state changes received by the children, and the LWCs do all the work.  I keep the parent Aura in case I ever need a child Aura.

Comment: actually I meant that they are wrapped in aura components, but only for navigation purposes. If I use my second lwc as a child, it would be the lightning component only

Comment: Ah, I see.  It sounds solid to me, then!

Comment: and what i would do if I were to choose this approach, is to assign my LWC1 as the parent, (as it is the main functionality) and use the LWC2 as the child, as it contains specific functionality that complements.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but would a screen flow where you can put your lwc component(s) and output/input the data/state between lwc screens and flow variables suffice? Could get rid of the aura wrapper though may end up being more complicated dealing with flow than just parent/child

Comment: @KrisGoncalves yes, I said in my earlier comment that the Aura wrappers are only used to implement the isUrlAddressable and navigate using NavigationMixin.